# DropDownList BackColor in IE7

Tags: asp.net, html, css

How do I change the DropDownList BackColor in IE7? In Firefox it correctly paints the whole DropDown, but in IE7 there always remains a white color in the border of the DropDown.

Answer (score 0):

This article may help: [Styling a ListBox aka Autopsy of a ListBox](http://chris.59north.com/post/Styling-a-ListBox-aka-Autopsy-of-a-ListBox.aspx)

I expect your particular problem is due to some padding inside the DropDown in IE7.